# JQuery Ajax request does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with a Ajax request. I used a lot of Ajax and never had problems but in this case it just does not work and I am looking for days into it now and can't find my error.

If you go to: http://sites.ondalocal.com.br/onodera/
Then submit the form with the button that says "Agendar agora!".

By clickung the following code is executed:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://186.202.184.93/vhosts/sites/wp-content/themes/Onodera_test/onodera.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        site : "1", 
        field : "3" 
    },
    success : function(data){
        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    }
});
```

the called php page does not contain errors. but the success function is never called, it always goes to error.

Could anyone please have a quick look at this?

Comment: Did you bother checking if your ajax stuff actually executes? CHeck the server if something gets through to it?

Comment: Could this fail due to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)?

Comment: What is status code of request? Check with firebug for firefox in console tab.

Comment: @kingkero - ding,ding,ding - ten points = "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: @adeneo [aw yeah!](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/106/887/backpain-1292835351.jpg)

Comment: This is not how you send JSON data, you have to send JSON string like ... `"{
        'site' : '1', 
        'field' : '3' 
    }",`

Answer (score 2):

check console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://186.202.184.93/vhosts/sites/wp-content/themes/Onodera_test/onodera.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sites.ondalocal.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.
```

[Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: You definitely can. Only the called server needs to accept it (see CORS) ;)